# Wordpress Edit window modification

Tags: wordpress

I want to add some note to Post Edit window so I can alert my Authors when they are going to add or edit post.

That could be simple styled text or some ticker or tabbed ui. Hope this would be enough to understand what I need help from you friends..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want an other pannel next/below a post/page edit/add screen?

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'extra_box' );

function extra_box()
{
    $cssId = 'extra_box';
    $frontendTitle = 'test';
    $callbackFunction = 'extra_box_content';
    $place = 'side';
    $prio = 'high';

    //add to pages
    add_meta_box($cssId, $frontendTitle, $callbackFunction, 'post', $place, $prio);
    add_meta_box($cssId, $frontendTitle, $callbackFunction, 'page', $place, $prio);
}

function extra_box_content()
{
    echo 'ITS A BOX';
}
```

look at:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

Comment: I put this code into function.php What I want to do is place one info box on the edit section so all author can read that note while posting an article.

Comment: @pixelngrain the frontendTitle ws empty that's whu id didn't show. I tested it and it works in your functions.php

Comment: Main question has been solved now I want to style it. Is it possible to style as per my choice? I see you have defined ID for that but when I am adding style with that ID in my theme style.css its not affecting. Can you please guide me where and how can I add class to style that box?

Comment: Okay instead of asking new question which is almost related. I want to add field into the same metabox or new nomatter. What I want is author can request me to add new category. fields would be. Root Category: input field, New Category: input field, Send Request: button. Once they will submit the request will be sent via email to the admin. Important: Email must show the author who sent the request. So I can keep tracking.

Comment: ask a new question, reference this question. the answer is to big for here. One hint I will give you now. You have to make a plugin of this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin.